# Loop through each element of the list

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

Hi i am new to python and i am trying to build a function which will select each element of the list store each element in a variable and do something (using a loop)

StrLst = ['aaa','bbbaaa','cccbbb','aaabbb']

## now i want the first element of the list which will be stored in a variable

LstEle = list[0]

use the LstEle variable

and then go to the next element and do the same keep doing this for the whole list

Comment: `contains` is an odd variable name.  It is best not to name variables after verbs.

Comment: The code you posted has a syntax error; you're using `//` as a comment, but in Python `#` is a comment.  Did you translate this from JavaScript or something?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski : But at least it's not as bad as using `list` as a variable name. And I'm not too happy with `string`, either. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring:  I saw `string`.  I totally missed `list`.  Tanmay, don't name your variables with the same names as Python's built-in functions.  It confuses the reader and hides the built-in function from future use.

Comment: come on guys that is just a pseudo code

Comment: Where do you want to store the other values of the list? In the same variable to do something with it in a loop, or in different variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any` function, like this

```
>>> any(item in input_string for item in my_list)
```

`any` will return `True` if the condition (`item in input_string`) is satisfied atleast once. In this case, it iterates through `my_list` and checks if the current item is in the `input_string` with the `in` operator. If any of the items in `my_list` is in the `input_string`, it will return `True`

Comment: actually i want to use that item if found i.e. i want to store that found item in a variable

Comment: @Tanmay What if there are more than one values which are found in the string?

Comment: that is fine even if more than one values are same, i want to store the whole string in the variable

Comment: @Tanmay Can you please edit your question and include a valid example for this case?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in which items are present, not just if any are present, you can use

```
[item for item in my_list if item in string]
```

Comment: Fair enough, the question had `list` as a variable name, i didn't want to confuse the asker.