# Select each element of the list (using loop)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

Hi i am new to python and i am trying to build a function which will select each element of the list at a time,store each element in a variable and do something (using a loop)

```
StrLst = ['aaa','bbbaaa','cccbbb','aaabbb']
```

now i want the first element of the list which will be stored in a variable

```
LstEle = list[0]    #i.e. LstEle = aaa
```

use the LstEle variable

and then go to the next element and do the same keep doing this for the whole list

Comment: I suggest using a for loop.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: This is word-for-word a duplicate of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25850711/3001761

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for-loop in order to achieve what you want.

```
for LstEle in StrLst:
    # do something with LstEle
```

In each iteration the current element will be accessible through `LstEle`.

Comment: how do you iterate to each element i.e. change the value in list [] brackets

Comment: It's iterating automatically because lists in python are iterable objects. I know this is question-answer site but I strongly suggest to read any of introducing into python book or internet tutorial.

Comment: @Tanmay also, learn to search: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4081217/3001761